# При попытке выполнить команду gulp через терминал пишет -bash: gulp: command not found

Tags: gulp

При попытке выполнить команду **gulp** через терминал пишет: `-bash: gulp: command not found`

Вот что было выведено прежде при локальной установке gulp:

```
npm WARN project@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN project@1.0.0 No repository field.
MacBook-Air-Andrej:maxxigento_t andrejdanickin$ gulp
-bash: gulp: command not found
MacBook-Air-Andrej:maxxigento_t andrejdanickin$ npm install gulp
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@3.0.8: graceful-fs version 3 and before will fail on newer node releases. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible.
npm WARN deprecated lodash@1.0.2: lodash@<3.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^4.0.0.
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs version 3 and before will fail on newer node releases. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible.
npm WARN project@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN project@1.0.0 No repository field.
MacBook-Air-Andrej:maxxigento_t andrejdanickin$ npm install gulp --save-dev
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@3.0.8: graceful-fs version 3 and before will fail on newer node releases. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible.
npm WARN deprecated lodash@1.0.2: lodash@<3.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^4.0.0.
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs version 3 and before will fail on newer node releases. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible.

npm WARN maxxigento_t@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN maxxigento_t@1.0.0 No repository field.
MacBook-Air-Andrej:maxxigento_t andrejdanickin$ gulp
-bash: gulp: command not found
```

Comment: Установите через sudo.  `sudo npm install gulp-install`

Comment: @Max не надо такое советовать. Не все вещи в этом мире решаются правами суперпользователя.

Comment: @D-side, он правильно советует. Gulp должен быть установлен и локально и глобально. И это указано в документации. Объяснения того, как устанавливать пакеты глобально без прав суперпользователя выходят за рамки вопроса.

Comment: @Denisgruzdev зависит от способа установки NodeJS, вообще говоря. Глобальность установки определяется флагом `-g`, но никак не правами.

Comment: @D-side, согласен, проглядел, sudo увидел и подумал, что совет - установить глобально.

Answer (score 1):

Наконец то нашел решение!!!

Чтобы дать вам немного контекста: Я побежал следующую команду для установки Gulp (модуль пакета узел) глобально:

```
npm install -g gulp
```

Установка успешно, но когда я запустил эту gulp команду в командной строке я получил ошибку.

> gulp: command not found

Оказалось, что он установлен "Глоток" в моем локальном каталоге, который `/Users/YOURUSERNAME/node_modules`, а не в глобальной папке `НПМ`.

Вы можете проверить это, выполнив команду:

```
npm root или npm root -g
```

Который возвращался мои личном каталоге `/Users/YOURUSERNAME/node_modules`, а не ожидаемое `/usr/local/lib/node_modules`.

После нескольких проб и ошибок, я, наконец, нашел решение. Вы должны изменить "NPM конфигурации префикс" следующим образом:

```
npm config set prefix /usr/local
```

Потом, когда я вновь побежал `npm root -g`, я получил нужную папку корневой: `/usr/local/lib/node_modules`

Когда я заново Gulp глобально (с `-g` парам) он, наконец, работал и оказалось, что это был теперь корректно устанавливается в глобальной папке НПМ. Йеай!

Всем СПАСИБО за поддержку и желание помочь!

Answer (score 0):

Gulp должен быть установлен и глобально и локально.

Comment: Или не помогает или я что то не так делаю или сделал

Comment: MacBook-Air-Andrej:temp_upd andrejdanickin$ sudo npm install gulp -g
Password:
.....
└── gulp@3.9.1

Comment: @ИванДраго, попробуйте ключ -g перед gulp. И вывод команды пришлите.

Comment: Вы бы добавили пример команды глобальной установки пакета (хоть абстрактного, `пакет`), это бы сняло множество вопросов. В идеале, конечно, в ответе же рассказать, зачем это надо и чем отличается.

Comment: Не помогает(( Ввожу так sudo npm install -g gulp

Comment: Хотя создает кучу пакетов /Users/andrejdanickin/.npm-packages/bin/gulp -> /Users/andrejdanickin/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js
/Users/andrejdanickin/.npm-packages/lib
└── gulp@3.9.1 ... дальше целое дерево пакетов

Comment: @ИванДраго, а /Users/../.npm-packages/bin есть в PATH?

Comment: Причем, с недавнего времени - двумя разными пакетами. Глобальный - `gulp-cli`, а локальный - просто `gulp`